# Google Wave as code repository and IDE?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, ide, google-wave

Is it possible to write a Google Wave plugin that turns it into an IDE for programming? With such an extension, Google Wave would be a replacement for Eclipse etc., and it would naturally be a code repository at the same time (replacing SVN, git, etc.).

Users (programmers) would be able to create code files directly in Wave and add collaborators to do pair programming etc. The whole codebase would live in a Wave folder, and an extension would do the building and compiling on the fly.

How would one go about writing such an extension?

Comment: A problem might be that all the text (the code that people are editing in that IDE) is not local.

Comment: and an other problem is that Google Wave is awfully slow for the moment (not to mention instabilities)

Comment: @SuperBloup: That's a problem *now*, but hopefully not down the road.

Comment: I think you should do it man! I think google has some docs about writing extensions, somewhere.

Comment: Someone might want to tag it VCS instead of SVN. Just saying.

Comment: @Austin: Haha, no way. I think it's so involved, it can only be done by Google itself. I bet it will require lots of changes to the Wave core code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [CodeRun IDE](http://www.coderun.com/ide/)? Except for the  collaboration aspect of google wave, or coding non-web apps, this might be ideal.

I expect coderun will become more collaborative as time goes on.

Comment: looks nice, although somewhat buggy too.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea and to be honest had thought of something similar myself. Stability and speed of Google Wave are valid points of course.

I see this being built over the Wave protocol than over Wave. I mean strip out some of the features of the Google Wave product but keep the underlying principles of Waves and collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

i definitely would want google to get an IDE, they have mostly everything already:
- Appengine
- Appengine SDK
- GWT
- Google code
- Google apps (docs, talk, mail, sites)
They just need to put it all together in a single IDE and make it online based (webapp) with offline capabilities, maybe HTML5 or gears so you can use it no matter the browser or OS you use.  Then this IDE connects to all the online tools mentioned before and you just have to write, junit test, run test, make some how-to's and wikis and commit. CodeRun is a good starter.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the first things which popped into my head when I recently watched the presentations from Google IO, and for Wave in particular. The demonstration of collaborating on the Sudoku app is a good example. The ability to replay conversations was particularly interesting and has obvious uses in developing as a team.